# django /admin showing react index.html page wiith when runing behind nginx

Tags: python, reactjs, django, nginx, lets-encrypt

I am following this guide [React-django-nginx](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/), I am unable to access /admin it shows blank page with react's index.html page code inside it. but when access /admin by hard refreshing the page then it works correctly.

all the configurations in `conf` file are same as this guide